# Double $http.post in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

we are using $http.post to send a request to our server and when the server doesn't reply in time (approx 3 secs) our angularjs client send another http.post. We have tracked this with tcpdump and we see 2 different $http.post.

This is our controller:

```
var request = Local.testPost();
request.then(function successCallback(response) {
  console.log(response);
}, function errorCallback(error) {
   console.log(error);
});
```

And this is our Local Service post:

```
this.testPost = function(){
    var data = 'token='+User.getToken();

    var request = $http(
        {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
             },
            url: self.server+'/api/cmd',
            data: data
        }
    );
    return request;
};
```

Our server logs 2 different post too...

How is possibile? 
Thanks everybody!

UPDATE: Tcpdump Log

```
 16:53:38.058379 IP 192.168.1.66.52515 > 8.ip-xxxxxx.eu.http: Flags [P.], seq 581:1162, ack 355, win 4106, options [nop,nop,TS val 206302095 ecr 194158267], length 581: HTTP: POST /api/cmd HTTP/1.1

16:53:41.843608 IP 192.168.1.66.52515 > 8.ip-xxxxx.eu.http: Flags [.], ack 709, win 4095, options [nop,nop,TS val 206305864 ecr 194161726], length 0

16:53:41.848302 IP 192.168.1.66.52515 > 8.ip-xxxxx.eu.http: Flags [F.], seq 1162, ack 709, win 4096, options [nop,nop,TS val 206305868 ecr 194161726], length 0

16:53:41.848918 IP 192.168.1.66.52522 > 8.ip-xxxxxx.eu.http: Flags [S], seq 4161058194, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 206305868 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0

16:53:41.884020 IP 192.168.1.66.52522 > 8.ip-xxxxxxx.eu.http: Flags [.], ack 3569763921, win 4117, options [nop,nop,TS val 206305903 ecr 194161768], length 0

16:53:41.884246 IP 192.168.1.66.52522 > 8.ip-xxxxxx.eu.http: Flags [P.], seq 0:581, ack 1, win 4117, options [nop,nop,TS val 206305903 ecr 194161768], length 581: HTTP: POST /api/cmd HTTP/1.1

16:53:41.884701 IP 192.168.1.66.52515 > 8.ip-xxxxxx.eu.http: Flags [.], ack 710, win 4096, options [nop,nop,TS val 206305903 ecr 194161768], length 0

16:53:45.629884 IP 192.168.1.66.52522 > 8.ip-xxxxxx.eu.http: Flags [.], ack 355, win 4106, options [nop,nop,TS val 206309616 ecr 194162704], length 0

16:53:54.452688 IP 192.168.1.66.52435 > 8.ip-xxxxxx.eu.http: Flags [.], ack 5234, win 4096, options [nop,nop,TS val 206318403 ecr 194164846], length 0

16:53:54.452696 IP 192.168.1.66.52435 > 8.ip-xxxxxx.eu.http: Flags [.], ack 5234, win 4096, options [nop,nop,TS val 206318403 ecr 194164846], length 0

16:53:54.452719 IP 192.168.1.66.52435 > 8.ip-xxxxxx.eu.http: Flags [F.], seq 1261, ack 5234, win 4096, options [nop,nop,TS val 206318403 ecr 194164846], length 0
```

Comment: What your developer tools network tab showing? Can you get a screenshot?

Comment: In the network tab i can only see one request sending...

Comment: In that case it might be something to do with the server. What your server stack? And is the behavior consistent will different browsers?

Comment: Our server stack is Nginx tornado4.3 python and yes we see this behavior also in an ionic app.

Comment: I have added a tcp dump log on our client

Comment: Where is the code that makes another request if first fails? Do you have more than one instance of controller? Note that setting controller in routing config and duplicating with `ng-controller` would create 2 instances

Comment: I dont' want to make another request if first fails. I don't have another controller and this is declared only in the app routing..

Comment: Another strange thing is that the second post is after 3 seconds...

Comment: Have you tried it in other browsers? Any way, it doesn't seem to do anything with `angularjs` tag. If the request isn't shown in network tab, the problem doesn't concern client script at all.

Comment: I have tried with an ionic app on my android phone and it's the same..
Im going to test on safari...

Comment: But you said *"our angularjs client send another http.post"* ....where is that done? Sounds like that code might not be right

Comment: You can monitor all network requests in chrome from here `chrome://net-internals/#events` to see details.

Comment: I can only see the second post on tcpdump and on our server. In the network tab for devs i see one only request.

Comment: Well if only one request in browser then problem is at server. Not sure why you posted all this client side code for that

Comment: Thanks @koox00 but also in this link i can only see one url request as a post and in tcpdump 2

Comment: @charlietfl i posted all this client side code because i see 2 different sent post from my client. It should be a client-side problem. When i send this post from other tools (like wget etc etc) i dont see 2 different post sending.

Comment: But you said you only see one in network. *"In the network tab for devs i see **one only request**"* Where's the backup request code then?

Comment: The code shown will not produce this problem by itself. Need a [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl that's the problem, i don't want backup request but it sends 2 of them.

Comment: Facts are getting very confusing and contradictory here. You said you have a backup request system but haven't shown us how it works. Create a demo that reproduces this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one possible cause could be if your server responds with `408` status, in this case some retry automatically run. You should not respond `408` if it's not a "real" `408`.

have a look at this:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4806

cheers